# RSpec can't load my non ActiveModel model classes

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I'm new to using RSpec in a Rails app and I can't get RSpec to see my Models :(

I added the following lines in my `Gemfile`

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

and installed it with

```
rails generate rspec::install
```

Then I created a `facebook_page.rb` file in `app/models/` directory, it's **not** an ActiveModel

```
class FacebookPage
  class << self
    # define class variables
    attr_accessor :app_id
    attr_accessor :app_secret
  end
end
```

And now I'm trying to test it so I added a `facebook_page_spec.rb` in `spec/models/` directory

```
describe FacebookPage do
  describe ".app_id" do
    it "should return the FB_APP_ID environment variable and thus not be null" do
      FacebookPage.app_id.should_not be_empty 
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

I get the following error :

```
/home/geoffroy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/models/facebook_page_spec.rb
/home/geoffroy/dev/mybandpage/spec/models/facebook_page_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant FacebookPage (NameError)
```

RSpec does not seem to load my model file.
Is it because it's not a subclass of ActiveRecord ?
How can I solve that ?

Many thanks in advance, best

Geoffroy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in `rails generate rspec::install` (double colon) try use `rails generate rspec:install`. Also try to run the test with the following command `bundle exec rspec spec`.

Did you `require "spec_helper"` in your test?

ps. This code is wrong:

```
class FacebookPage
  class << self
    # define class variables
    attr_accessor :app_id
    attr_accessor :app_secret
  end
end
```

Basically in this example you're defining instance variables on the singleton class, try use this approach: http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor

Comment: Hey! You were very helpful, thanks a lot, I missed require "spec_helper". And I will look at the cattr right away!!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not including `require 'rails_helper'` at the start of the spec.